# Formula from a form having one dirac delta to a form having two dirac delta

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, gm.general-mathematics

I'd like to ask at which condition I can transform a formula with one delta function to a form with two delta function.

Suppose a physical system has a quasi-continuous energy-level spectrum $E_1$, $E_2$, $\ldots$, $E_\infty$, the response $\sigma$ of the system is expressed as:

$\sigma=\sum_{mn}|p_{mn}|^2\delta(E_m-E_n)(\frac{\partial f}{\partial E})_{E_n}$.

where $|p_{mn}|^2$ denotes transtion probability, and $f$ is a fermi-Dirac function. This may be written as:

$\sigma=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dE\sum_{mn}|p_{mn}|^2\delta(E-E_n)\delta(E-E_m)\frac{\partial f}{\partial E}$.

Is the insertion of an addition delta function correct?

Comment: yes, this is correct, because $\delta(E-E_n)\delta(E-E_m)=\delta(E-E_n)\delta(E_n-E_m)$ and then you integrate out the first delta function (note a typo: $t_{mn}$ in your second formula should be $p_{mn}$).

Comment: I am evaluating the fomula numerically, by replacing the delta function with a Lorentzian wit small broadening parameter. I find these two forms show very different behavior.

Comment: Then you are learning something about the pitfalls of numerically integrating rapidly varying functions.

Comment: Do you mean: because Lorentzian with a small broadening parameter is a rapidly varying function, so it is difficult to handle the intergal well? In this sense, it would be more difficult for the form with two delta function.

Comment: I actually do not understand your first formula; if $E_m$ is discrete, the Dirac delta function $\delta(E_n-E_m)$ should be a Kronecker delta $\delta_{nm}$, shouldn't it?

Comment: It is actually a quasi-delta-function (but not a Kronecker delta); that means, the first formula is valid only in the thermodynamic limit, where the energy-level spectrum is a continumm.

Comment: @CarloBeenakker No, the expression with the Dirac delta is correct. This is actually quite similar (if not the same) as what happens with the Fermi's golden rule. The delta appears by normalization, because one is evaluating some matrix element of a Hamiltonian between its eigenstates. But it always disappears because the transition rate as it stands doesn't make much sense experimentally, and one has to integrate over the phase space. After such integration one has a well defined, sensible rate - without any Delta.

Comment: @Daniel Castro I am wondering can m=n in this formula?